# Can an Elm function have a docstring?

Tags: elm

Python has them and I find them very useful:

```
def awesome_fn(x, y):
    """"
    Calculates some awesome function of x and y.
    """"
    .
    .
    .
```

Then in the iPython REPL you can query it with

```
In [1]: awesome_fn?
Signature: awesome_fn(x, y)
Docstring: Calculates some awesome function of x and y.
File:      ...
Type:      function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to specify documentation for a module using the following [documentation format](http://package.elm-lang.org/help/documentation-format):

```
module Maybe exposing (Maybe(Just,Nothing), andThen, map, withDefault, oneOf)

{-| This library fills a bunch of important niches in Elm. A `Maybe` can help
you with optional arguments, error handling, and records with optional fields.

# Definition
@docs Maybe

# Common Helpers
@docs map, withDefault, oneOf

# Chaining Maybes
@docs andThen

-}
```

and for a method:

```
{-| Convert a list of characters into a String. Can be useful if you
want to create a string primarly by consing, perhaps for decoding
something.

    fromList ['e','l','m'] == "elm"
-}
fromList : List Char -> String
fromList = ...
```

But it's not possible so far to view these docs from `repl`. There's even [an issue](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-repl/issues/126) related to this.

On the other hand, there's [elm-oracle](https://github.com/ElmCast/elm-oracle) library, which allows you to integrate documentation hints into an editor (and it's already integrated into [the popular ones](https://github.com/ElmCast/elm-oracle#projects-that-use-elm-oracle)), or even run it in command line as:

```
elm-oracle FILE query
```